# How to Properly free() and malloc() in C++

Tags: c++, c, malloc, free

I have a function delete_dungeon() that is supposed to delete the current dungeon and create a new one when a user goes up or down stairs. I had it working in C and now that we switched to using C++ I have gotten these errors:

- "malloc(): memory corruption (fast)"
- "corrupted size vs prev_size (fastbins)"
- "double free or corruption (out)"

These have occurred either when I try to move when the new dungeon is generated or if I'm able to move, when I try and go up or down another staircase. Here is my delete_dungeon() function in C++. I did check to make sure that these were the only things I was using malloc on and I am freeing everything that has been.

```
    void delete_dungeon(Dungeon *dungeon, Turn turn[], int *init, int *num_characters){
         free(dungeon->up_stairs);
         free(dungeon->down_stairs);
         free(dungeon->rooms);
         free(turn);
         free(dungeon->mons);

         dungeon->num_rooms = (rand() % (15 - 6 + 1)) + 6; //Generates between 6-15 rooms
         dungeon->num_up = (rand() % 5) + 1; //Will place 1-5 up staircases
         dungeon->num_down = (rand() % 5) + 1;

         dungeon->up_stairs = (UpStairs*) (malloc(dungeon->num_up * sizeof(UpStairs)));
         dungeon->down_stairs = (DownStairs*) (malloc(dungeon->num_down * sizeof(DownStairs)));
         dungeon->rooms = (Room*) (malloc(dungeon->num_rooms * sizeof(Room)));
         dungeon->mons = (Monster*) (malloc(dungeon->num_mons * sizeof(Monster)));
         
         int num_stairs_placed[2] = {0, 0};
         *init = 0;
         *num_characters = dungeon->num_mons + 1;
         turn = (Turn*) (malloc(*num_characters * sizeof(Turn)));
         dungeon->total_monsters_faced += dungeon->num_mons;
         create_monsters(dungeon);
         fill_dungeon(dungeon);
         create_dungeon_map(dungeon, num_stairs_placed, 0);
         place_monsters(dungeon);
         do_maps(dungeon);
}
```

Comment: There's a lack of information to make a [mre]. One problem is that the memory allocated and assigned to `turn` is leaked on function exit (and not returned to the caller).

Comment: `double free` is because you didn't `malloc`'ed the memory that you're trying to free, but for the rest, we cannot help you without a minimal reproductible example.

Comment: You need to remove all, and only, code not needed to replicate the problem and confirm that the code you have given us is sufficient to replicate the problem. If you can't replicate the problem with just this code, that means the problem may not be in this code.

Comment: @Fayeure ; or as mentioned in the error message "corruption".  All three can be caused by either heap or allocated block corruption.  Buffer overrun or continuing to write to a free'd block could equally be the cause, and could have happened at any time prior to detection.

Answer (score 1):

These are runtime checks that occur when `free()` or `malloc()` are called. WHen the checks are enabled the integrity of the heap or the validity of the block being returned  to the heap is verified.

Heap corruption, or corruption of the meta-data associated with an allocate block most often caused by a buffer overrun in an adjacent memory block, or continuing to write to a block that has already been freed.

The chances are that unless you have made other changes, when you used C compilation, the error was also there, but the runtime checks were not enabled or supported.

Unfortunately the likelihood is that the causal error is not in the code you have included, and did not occur at the point where the library detected the error.  Tools such as Valgrind may assist in tracking down such errors more quickly, but generally it comes down to better and more careful coding practices.